# open a .mdb database with a visual studio 6 program

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access

I try openning a `.mdb` file using `CDaoDatabase`, but at `Open()` catches an error: `Unrecognised database format`. I created the database first in MSAcces2007 and saved the file as `.mdb`, then i installed MSAcces2003 and created the file again, but there's the same error. Does anyone have a clue what's happening?

```
CString pathDB = "SMACDB\\Transports.mdb";
CDaoDatabase dbTransp;

try
{
    dbTransp.Open(pathDB);

    CDaoRecordset rs(&dbTransp);
    COleVariant var1;
    rs.Open(dbOpenSnapshot, "SELECT * FROM Transporturi");
    while (!rs.IsEOF())
    {
        var1 = rs.GetFieldValue(1);
        CString val = (LPCTSTR)var1.bstrVal;
        g_carRestrict.pCarNmb.AddTail(val);
        var1 = rs.GetFieldValue(2);
        g_carRestrict.pAllowed.AddTail(var1.lVal);

        rs.MoveNext();
    }

    rs.Close();
    dbTransp.Close();
}
catch (CDaoException *pEx)
{
    pEx->Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual C++ 6 uses DAO 3.5 by default which does not support Access 2000 or later formats. To have MFC uses DAO 3.6, change the runtime version number to 6.01.

Suggested reading:

[You receive an "Unrecognized database format" error message when you open a database created with Access 2000](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236991)

Comment: Oh...After reading the post from the link and comments in .MAK files in MFC SRC folder i realised i could get over my head by making changes like those described. If i create a database using MSAcces'97, opening it should work, right?

Comment: Thank you for your response! After all i created the databese using `Create()` and `Execute()` methods as i have little time remaining for completing the task related to this database, but when i will be out of the woods i will try your method.